# code moved from build.gradle to groovy failing

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have some functionality of git commits in a task of type exec in build.gradle,

```
task getCommits(type: Exec){
// Some code goes here
.
.
commandLine "git", "log", "${previousVersionString}..${releaseVersion}"
}
```

above code works fine in build.gradle

As a result of clean up activity I'm taking this code out of build.gradle and putting it in a groovy class but it says can not resolve commandLine.

I'm very much new to gradle and groovy,
Can anybody suggest where I'm going wrong

Comment: Gradle files are a DSL, not pure Groovy...  You can't just lift lines of code and put them in a separate file.  You could write a custom task and add it to your buildSrc https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

Comment: If you just want to outsource Gradle functionality into other files, use separate `.gradle` scripts and include them via `apply from: 'path/to/script'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**commandLine** is Gradle method, that cannot be  called outside

To execute command line in any groovy script:

```
def proc = ['git', 'log', "${previousVersionString}..${releaseVersion}"].execute()
println (proc.err.text ?: proc.text)
```

Comment: ok, and can you provide the translateion for this line as well   commandLine "git", "tag", "-l", "${searchVersionString}", "--sort=-version:refname"

Comment: But you'd be better with a custom task yeah?  That looks less clean than the original...

Comment: Yeah we can definitely, but I was writing a plugin and this is first time I'm writing it, I followed the common style of groovy classes as a plugin, that's why I'm doing this

Comment: Are you writing Gradle plugin? In this case you still can use commandLine: project.task('getCommits', type: Exec).commandLine("git", "log", "${previousVersionString}..${releaseVersion}")

Comment: Yes a gradle plugin, but I have taken out the functionality of git in a groovy class thats why need to translate it to groovy, otherwise in build.gradle it works like charm. BDW running above code as a plugin gives fetal:ambiguous argument